# Approximately directed graph of logic types

Tags: logic

*I'm not sure if this is the right stack to post this question.*

Given there are many types of logic; Syllogistic, Symbolic, Modal, Deontic, Temporal, Epistemic, (non)monotonic, formal, informal, FOL, Propositional, Predicate, and the list goes on, I am struggling to understand how they relate to one another (some more than others).

Can they be represented in some form of (approximately) directed graph?  Has anyone made an attempt to do this?  Is there a reference I can read that would help me understand how the categories relate to one another?

I am, in asking this question, more interested in developing an overall  mental map than looking for specific differences between the categories, which I can determine by reading about each.
Cheers.

Comment: Some are order by inclusion according to the expressive power of the language: propositional logic is the simplest (there is no analysis inside the elementary sentence). The next step is predicate logic: first order, second order and so on, according to linguistic entities that we can quantify: first order- only individual variables, second order- quantifier apply to predicate of individual variables, and so on.

Comment: Syllogism is a subset of FOL: monadic predicate logic, i.e. predicates of individual variables are unary predicates (properties) only.

Comment: Deontic, Temporal, and Epistemic are all special cases of Modal (as is Alethic, which is the kind of modal logic most commonly used in introductory material - it's the one where box means "necessarily" and diamond means "possibly").

Answer (score 1):

I haven't seen an example of exactly what you're looking for, but if you're interested in trying to design such a graph on your own terms, I do have some suggested reading for you.

One general theory about the relationship between logic and graphs is Alessio Moretti's NOT theory. ["The Geometry of Logical Opposition"](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.169.1058&rep=rep1&type=pdf) has an emphatically philosophical introduction that addresses the issue as such; the rest of the book covers how Moretti cashes out the intro. Technically, the particular way in which Moretti reimagines the epistemic foundations of logic does not lend itself to an easy translation in terms of comparisons of more classically founded logics. But as a theory of logical operators, I could see it being adapted into an idea about how sets of logical operators from different domains (FOL, modal, deontic, etc.) might be part of some graph-theoretic superstructure.

Again more on the epistemological than the strictly logical side are ["Coherentism via Graphs"](https://scholar.harvard.edu/files/sberker/files/coherentism-via-graphs3a.pdf) and ["Infinite Cycles and the Graphical Approach to
Epistemic Justification"](https://bcmullins.github.io/images/ecej.pdf). But these deal with borderline logical structures (pure inference sequences/structures) so one can vaguely imagine situating specific inference types in terms of their place in such epistemic graphs (especially if e.g. epistemic logic is given a relevant special place in the graph one is aiming for, respecting the inference types).

Next, although these would only cover logic types of a classical/neoclassical bent, there are the (very simple) charts of "large cardinals" in set theory. Now it is possible to define various large cardinals in a uniform way (the doctrine of elementary embeddings) but nevertheless some admit (and were originally conceived) of characterizations in terms of logical variations. For example, indescribables are defined in terms of special variations over the [Lévy hierarchy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%A9vy_hierarchy), which has to do with existential and universal quantifiers (if I understand the material correctly), and weakly/strongly compacts can be defined in terms of infinitary logic. Then, IIRC, there are extendibles which come from varying the order of the infinitary logic upward. So, modulo classical/neoclassical logic types, we might try out graphing their relations "parallel to" the large-cardinal types with which they are entangled in the relevant way. So we'd have at least part of the overall graph you're looking for.

But overall, I imagine such an overall graph being a very peculiar affair. Not absolutely impossible, but of questionable theoretical utility. We might have to partition the graph in possibly strict ways, having a sort of "metagraph" instead, to juxtapose paraconsistent logic with paracomplete (intuitionistic) logic, and these with FOL, and so on. Moreover, some of the descriptors of a logic type can be applied to other descriptors in such a way that we would not have deontic logic, say, as a single node separate from the paraconsistent, nonmonotonic, etc. nodes, but we would have paraconsistent deontic, nonmonotonic deontic, etc. nodes, and so on and on. However, once we had arrived at a sufficient algorithm for sorting out how the different type descriptors fit together as such, I daresay we would be liable to have ended up with a metagraph complicated enough to require an explanation in the prose section of the essay in which the metagraph would be presented, such that the prose section might as well replace the presentation of the metagraph anyway, as far as goes the theoretical helpfulness of the graph-theoretic display vs. the prose explanation.

Just to emphasize how extraordinary a task this would be, here's a list (by no means exhaustive) of how many "variables" there are in defining different logics:

> Number of truth values (classically 2 (for *true* = 1 and *false* = 0); postclassically, as many as 2<sup>ℵ<sub>0</sub></sup> (fuzzy logic), which opens the door to arbitrarily many, and maybe even numbers less than 0 or greater than 1, "hypertruth" and "hyperfalsity" so to say).

> Use/nature of truth tables.

> The number and content of various axioms (such as in the different modal logics). Might or might not exhaustively overlap the question of how many basic operators the logic has/paraconsistency and paracompleteness conditions (if these count as variations over the negation and disjunction operators, say).

> The illocutionary force of the logic (usually assertoric, but there is also erotetic logic and at least imperative programming, if not imperative logic outright).

> The order of the logic (first-, second-, etc.).

> Whether the logic is infinitary, and if so, what its ℒ(κ,λ) signature is.

> Monotonicity/nonmonotonicity.

> Justification/deontic/other normative conditions (as in justification and deontic logic).

> Specific modalities (e.g. temporal).

And so on and on. The kind of graph that might result from assigning nodes to all the variations and their interpolations would arguably not even be recognizable as a graph so much as the skeleton of a crystallized continuum.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend working through Graham Priest's [Introduction to Non-Classical Logic](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521670268). It'll give you an outline of the logical terrain and indicate relationships among logics in terms of what they count as valid.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a slightly opinionated but probably useful simplification. The single, most important logic is [classical first-order logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic) (henceforth FOL). It's used all over the place and there are many important first-order theories, including but not limited to ZFC and Peano Arithmetic.

This answer is an extremely brief overview of things that are more expressive or less expressive than FOL. It's supposed to be rough and impressionistic.

If you encounter a new system, a good way to classify it is to compare its expressiveness to FOL. The various modal logics make a good *yardstick* below the FOL one ... and I think the infinitary logics make a good yardstick above FOL but I don't know much about them.

There are systems that are more expressive than FOL, including [second-order logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second-order_logic#Semantics) (although you can punch it back down to FOL-level by using Henkin semantics), [infinitary logic](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-infinitary/), [independence-friendly logic](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-if/), [dependence logic](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-dependence/). Intuitively, these logics seem like FOL plus something extra, like possibly-restricted quantification over functions and relations, or infinitely long formulas. These systems do not have paraphrases into FOL; they are fundamentally more expressive.

There are systems that have the same expressivity as FOL. These include [most plural logics](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/plural-quant/), [free logics](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-free/), [monadic second order logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monadic_second-order_logic). Some of these systems have quite simple paraphrases into FOL. I'm also including variants of FOL like FOL with multiple sorts here.

Then there's the stuff that's weaker than FOL that includes the [modal logics](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-modal/), [relevance logic](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-relevance/), [intuitionistic logic](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-intuitionistic/), [propositional calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propositional_calculus), etc.